# iPad 2 darkening of screen down left hand edge

Tags: ipad

I've just bought an iPad 2 and it seems to have a very subtle screen fault: a very slight darkening down the left hand edge of the screen, so that if e.g. a document is being viewed on a white background, the left hand edge (say 1/2 cm) actually appears to be a very light grey. It does seem to be a physical screen issue, in that it appears across different applications, and with the device turned upside down, the fault is now on the right hand side. It's quite subtle, but quite irritating.

For what it's worth, I'm upgrading from an iPad 1 and never had this problem with the previous iPad.

Has anyone heard of/experienced this issue? I assume it's an actual hardware fault and I'll have to take the device back to the shop, and not simply some secret calibration issue...?

Comment: It is indeed a hardware issue. Take it to Apple for servicing.

Comment: I agree with @cksum. As a result I am closing this question as it appears to be an edge case.

Comment: OK, shame about the trigger-happy closing: whether indeed this was a narrow or wide issue was precisely what I was trying to find out, and now we won't know...

Comment: If Apple has not released a recall, or posted a service bulletin, then you can be sure it is only affecting a small batch of units. If you'd like to investigate the matter more, head over to https://discussions.apple.com